# Mongo query subdocument and print on one line

Tags: mongodb

Am using mongodb 3.0 - If I have a doc like this(simple version):

```
{
    "_id": "10",
    "Timestamp": ISODate("2015-09-07T09:54:45.000Z"),
    "StudentData": [
        {
            "Name": "John"
            "Town": "ZZZZZ"
            "Available": true
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mary"
            "Town": "XXXXXX"
            "Available": false
        }
   ]
}
```

I need the results printed like this:

```
Mon Sep 07 2015 10:54:45 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),John,true
Mon Sep 07 2015 10:54:45 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),Mary,false
```

I have tried this:

```
db.students.find(
    {_id:10})
    .forEach(function(x){
        print(
            x.Timestamp
            +","+
            x.StudentData.Name 
            +","+ 
            x.StudentData.Available
            );
        });
```

But I get the result back as

**Mon Sep 07 2015 10:54:45 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),undefined,undefined**

Maybe this is the right track:

```
var cursor = 
    db.students.aggregate(
        {$match: {_id: "10"}},
        {$unwind: '$StudentData'});

    print(cursor.result);
```

Or am I way of the mark??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there with the aggregation framework approach as **[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** will "split" the array to output a document per array element, thus the pipeline result will have the two documents that you can print. Since the **[`aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)** method returns a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor), you need to iterate the cursor to access the documents and print them by using the **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** method.  Consider the following tweak:

```
var printStudentData = function (doc) {
    print(doc.Timestamp +", " + doc.StudentData.Name + ", " + doc.StudentData.Available);
}
var cur = db.students.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: "10"}},
    {$unwind: '$StudentData'}
]);
cur.forEach(printStudentData);
```

**Output**

```
Mon Sep 07 2015 10:54:45 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), John, true
Mon Sep 07 2015 10:54:45 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time), Mary, false
```

If you want to stick with the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** cursor, then you would need to iterate over the `StudentData` array whilst you are in the **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** cursor loop, something like:

```
var printStudentData = function (doc) {
    print(doc.Timestamp +", " + doc.StudentData.Name + ", " + doc.StudentData.Available);
};
var result = db.students.find({_id: "10"});

result.forEach(function (x){
    x.StudentData.forEach(function (data){
        var obj = { 
            "StudentData": {} 
        };
        obj["Timestamp"] = x.Timestamp;
        obj["StudentData"]["Name"] = data.Name;
        obj["StudentData"]["Available"] = data.Available;
        printStudentData(obj);      
    });     
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer.. Thanks